Проверка баланса через API для провайдера интернета ТТК
Проверять свой баланс ТТК (lk.ttk.ru) в полуавтоматическом виде.

Секретные данные вносим в переменные окружения (.env)
LOGIN=XXX
PASSWORD=XXX

После чего их считывываем, авторизуемся и проверяем баланс
from enum import StrEnum
import os
import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

class Credentials(StrEnum):
    url = 'https://lk.ttk.ru/api'
    login = os.getenv("LOGIN")
    password = os.getenv("PASSWORD")


class Endpoints(StrEnum):
    login_by_account = '/auth/loginByAccount'
    user = '/user'


session = requests.session()

account = session.post(
    url=f'{Credentials.url}{Endpoints.login_by_account}',
    json={
        'login': Credentials.login,
        'password': Credentials.password,
    }
)

balance = session.post(
    url=f'{Credentials.url}{Endpoints.user}',
    json={
        'contract_id': account.json()[0]['contract_id']
    }
)

print(balance.json()['balance'])


С чего вы взяли, что login/password, размещенные в environment защищены в большей степени, нежели размещенные прямо в  теле скрипта?

Я открыт к советам, так как не являюсь профессионалом ;) Как минимум они не попадают в гит, если с .gitignore все в порядке.
